# How to check if an object is in the CPU cache?

Tags: java, caching, cache-control, low-level, cpu-cache

Is there a way in java to check if a specific object is in the CPU cache? Is there a way to test if reading/writing one of its fields will make a cache miss?

I wrote java programs in the past, but not complex ones, and now I have to do some academic research in java.

If this is not possible, is there a generic way to simulate this kind of thing?
And is this possible in low-level programming, such as C?

Comment: Java programs all run in a virtual machine...so to put it simply, no.

Comment: I would be pretty shocked if there were a way to do this.  Such details should be hidden from the programmer...

Comment: I'm not sure this is even possible in C or even assembly. Any attempt to "check" the address will automatically bring it into cache.

Comment: I mean, if you have some object with a field that points to another object. The second object may not be in the cache, but we can know its address. Is it possible to know it is not in the cache by its address? (I know I'm still thinking in a C-way).

Comment: This seems to resemble a Master's Thesis. So you'll have to do the research, if you're confident to take the challenge. I suggest performing a search on "Java JVM memory mode", or similar. One link can be http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf . This seems like someone else's Thesis :)

Comment: Even the question `is X in the cache` is not well defined. To be of any use, the question would have to consider what kind of state the object is at the moment (e.g. if the cacheline the object is in is exclusive to a different processor does this count as "in cache" for the other processor? What if the object crosses cachelines? etc.)

Comment: The Original Android - your guess was correct :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR - No

In Java the JVM shields you from the CPU so this kind of low-level information is, by design, not exposed to the program.

Moreover, even if you go lower-level languages (e.g., C) and used some assembly-level hacks, I can hardly imagine where you could get meaningful data about cache status, for the following reason: the cache is dynamic - new data is continuously loaded into it and (older) data is continuously  flushed from it. In each given moment you have several processes running on top of your CPU each one of them spawning at least one thread (probably more than that) - the combined activity of all these threads affects the cache and the data stored in it.

Thus, even if you could get a Y/N answer to the question `is object X in cache` then this answer will become obsolete the minute you get it.

Comment: Is there a way to know about a cache-miss after it happened?

Comment: For what its worth, scratchpad memory and MIPS's cache instructions are examples of how some CPUs expose the cache to the application.

Comment: @Oren you can check cache misses using MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.LLC_MISS  perf. counter (for L3 cache) by VTune or any other profiler.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said: no.

And even if you could query the cache for specific data, theres no telling if the whole object is in the cache, because there is no such notion at such a low level.